# Zooming into specific grids on a UISCROLLVIEW

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview

i.e size 330 by 230 each which lays out nicely in a 3 by 3 grid(3 columns , 3 rows). When we tap on it needs to zoom in and I need to be able to scroll around with paging enabled. (This only works if the frame of the scrollview is the size of the screen). i.e frame = cgrectmake(0,0,1024,768);

I actually got the zooming to work accordingly for the grids in the end but the main issue i had was the scrolling. Because the scrollview size triples, the actual origins change so if I try to set the frame to the screen size, then  the zoom moves back to 0,0 which looks odd(very hard to explain). Anyways to cut it short, this is what I am trying to do:

zoom into the specific grid according to location of the tap then scroll around when zoomed in but using paging enabled.

Any suggestions appreciated. I also tried using anchor points etc..

The code for the transformation is as follows:

I did not change any anchor points, so that zooms in the centre and increases the size by 3. I believe that now the top left corner of the scrollview is not 0,0 anymore.

```
 CGAffineTransform t = self.backgroundView.transform;
    t = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(3, 3);
    self.backgroundView.transform = t;//scrollview.
    self.backgroundView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(vw,vh);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post some code for how you are doing the zooming? The content positions should not change when zoomed, the zoomFactor simply tells the scroll view to show the enlarged content.

Comment: Can you post the actual zooming code in your original question.... do you use the viewForZoom methods of the UIScrollView or are you applying a transform to the view? (if it's the latter then you shouldn't be...)

Comment: I am applying transform to the view.Thanks for the answer. Any reason why I should not apply transform and use the zoom method for the uiscrollview?

Comment: The zooming functionality of the UIScrollView is intended for the problem you are trying to solve. If you use the zooming in the scrollview the positions and content offsets are preserved regardless of the zoom level, so at a zoom level of 1 (normal) a view at position 50,25 will still have the same position at a zoom of 2 (zoomed in twice the size).

Comment: No worries, we all do it! :) Good luck.... btw don't forget to implement the delegate method viewForZoom etc... if you don't it won't zoom, had me stumped for a while the first time I tried it... check for an online example.